# How to handle multi user and single user in the JMeter same Thread group

Tags: jmeter

I  have a scenario where multi users and single users should be there in the same thread group. Multi users should execute concurrently and single users should execute sequentially. How to handle this in the same thread group?

Comment: This is what happens when you use multi users, can you explain what's not working as expected?

Comment: The issue here is the API's used by the multi users and single users is in the same thread group. I cannot separate them.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want certain [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) to be executed sequentially, i.e. only one request of that kind should be executed at any given moment - put the relevant Sampler under the [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller)
2. If you want certain Samplers to be executed in parallel - put them under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)